# Allow SVGs in the HTML Sanitizer

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to allow SVGs in the HTML Sanitizer, but every configuration I tried didn't work and I get the error `User Warning: Element 'svg' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)` from the HTMLPurifier most of the time.

I followed the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/configurations/shopware/html-sanitizer.html) and this is the last configuration I tried.

```yaml
shopware:
  html_sanitizer:
    sets:
      -   name: basic
          tags: [ "svg" ]
          attributes: []
          options:
            - key: HTML.Trusted
              value: true
            - key: CSS.Trusted
              value: true
          custom_attributes:
            - tags: [ "svg" ]
```

I know that there is some stuff missing, but I didn't even get a basic `<svg></svg>` to work.

Answer (score 0):

The message you are seeing is generated by HTMLpurifier. There is an open issue [about SVG support](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/issues/88): It seems to be not easy to filter SVGs properly, in a way to be safely usable.

That means, even if there would be a configuration to allow all `<svg>` tag, you still would be open to security risks.

You can of course, always [disable the full sanitizer](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/configurations/shopware/html-sanitizer.html#configuration), while this is not recommended. But as the chain is as strong as its weakest link, it does not make much difference whether to allow unsafe SVGs or allow all HTML.

#### Risks of Disabling the Sanitizer

As far as I know, if the sanitizer is turned off, someone with content editing rights can add JavaScript to the page to get more privileges. However, turning off the sanitizer doesn't increase risks for attackers without admin panel access.

#### Alternatives

The better option would be to work on the above mentioned issue and contribute SVG support to the HTML purifier.

Also, depending on your original use case, why you want to use SVGs in the CMS, there might be better alternatives: If you need only a predefined set of SVGs, for example icons, there could be a way to select from these. But the I suggest to open a new question.